# Drupal JQuery broken?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

Not sure what's going on but the Jquery.js is dying on me with "d is not null". This came out of no where. I can't seem to figure out how to fix it it.

Screenshot of firebug:

[image: imgur.com/6K6fq.png]

[image: imgur.com/RJZHD.png]

From this drupal link [link](http://drupal.org/node/317371) Michelle (3rd comment) claims this is Collapsible forum containers issue? (Which as far as I know I am not using?) but it doesn't seem to help?

Anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like this belongs in a Drupal issue queue, if it isn't already.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, but really needed the functionality of Webform Conditional. If you really want to use Webform Conditional, you might try making the fixes suggested on this page:

http://drupal.org/node/788952

Worked PERFECTLY for me.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the  Webform Conditional module and the problem disappeared.